# Can’t render animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I render as animation the render doesn’t work, the window appears but there’s no image or any statistics of the render. What I find weird is that I can render a still image perfectly fine and I rendered two other render layers in the same scene fine. This render layer is just the background as the other two had it set as transparent.

Comment: Hi, please add your blend file because you told us the symptoms, but nearly nothing what you have done. Could be a lot of reasons. If you don't want to let us guess...just provide your blend file, thx.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure that I can since the file is over 100 mb and the only service I know of (Blend Exchange) has a 30 mb limit.

Comment: Have you enabled _File Extensions_ in the _Output Properties_? Or have you rendered the animation before without changing a filename and _Overwrite_ is disabled?

Comment: Hi, @Cabbage, see if you can strip down a toy version of your file to the absolute minimum that shows the error. (A step you should probably be taking anyway, to take a shot at debugging)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I fixed the problem, but it was a weird solution:

I changed the output path in the *Output Properties* tab from "tmp" to another folder, although it worked before in "tmp" for the other layers, and there was a node in the Composite window for saving to a specific folder.